# Координаты отрезка, параллельного заданному отрезку

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Имеются координаты исходного отрезка AB. Нужно нарисовать стрелку EF. Расстояние между отрезком и стрелкой задается константой.

Я написал метод, который возвращает координаты n-ной части отрезка. С его помощью получаю координаты точек C и D.

```
private static PointF GetSegmentPart(PointF start, PointF end, float lambda)
{
    return new PointF(
        (start.X + lambda * end.X) / (1 + lambda),
        (start.Y + lambda * end.Y) / (1 + lambda));
}

var c = GetSegmentPart(a, b, 1f/3);
var d = GetSegmentPart(a, b, 3);
```

Еще могу получить вектор, перпендикулярный отрезку CD:

```
var vector = new PointF(c.Y - d.Y, d.X - c.X);
```

Как можно получить координаты точек E и F, зная вектор-перпендикуляр и координаты точек C и D?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ответ - Никак! Этих стрелок может быть бесконечно.

Comment: Во первых надо определить точку начала стрелки на отрезке AB, во вторых направление перпендикуляра (их может быть 2).

Comment: Ну точки начала и конца стрелки на отрезке AB это C и D. Вообще, стрелка нужна справа от отрезка. На данном примере найденный вектор направлен в нужную сторону. Возможно, если покрутить отрезок, то нужно будет определиться с направлением вектора.

Comment: Как же "никак"? На бумаге я могу без проблем такое нарисовать. Значит и запрограммировать можно.

Comment: раз есть вектор, значит вы можете построить на этом векторе отрезок заданной длины, начинающийся с прямой AB, значит можете найти точку пересечения вектора и стрелки EF. Останется просто найти прямую проходящую через найденную точку и параллельную отрезку AB. А дальше на этой прямой по обе стороны от найденной точки помечаете точки, удаленные от найденной на равное расстояние, т.е. на расстояние `|EF| / 2`. Дальше останется только с направлением определиться, если очень грубо - точка, ближайшая к A будет началом, а ближайшая к B будет вашей стрелкой. Здесь писать больше чем делать

Comment: Есть нормализованный вектор-перпендикуляр (V), есть длинна стрелки (L), Есть расстояние между стрелкой и отрезком (R), есть нормализованный вектор паралель (dc), значит (x1 = Cx + Vx * R) (y1 = Cy + Vy * R) (x2 = x1 + dcx * L) (y2 = y1 + dcy * L), Да! Векторы должны быть **нормализованы**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так у вас почти всё есть уже.

У вас есть вектор, параллельный вектору CE (это `vector`). И у вас есть длина вектора CE. Поэтому делаете так:

```
var l = (длина vector);
var CE = vector / l * <длина CE>;
var E = C + CE;
var F = E + CD;
```

Плохая новость: у вас, кажется, неподходящая для геометрических вычислений структура данных. `PointF` не поддерживает ни сложение, ни векторные операции, так что вам придётся либо всё писать вручную (это несложно), либо перейти на [`System.Windows.Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и [`System.Windows.Vector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), которые поддерживают эти операции из коробки.

Comment: Спасибо. Вот этих операций мне и не хватало. Переходить на Wpf-ные структуры не получится из-за архитектуры приложения. Так что обходимся тем, что есть.

Comment: @Vlad: Тогда, возможно, имеет смысл написать небольшую геометрическую библиотеку: методы типа «длина» и «точка минус точка равно вектор» часто пригождаются.

Comment: Нечто подобное есть, но там ничего подходящего не оказалось.